# Show sweet alert dynamically depending on flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, sweetalert

so I have a form from which I am checking if data exists in a mysql table. If it does, and if user has checked the checkbox, same form's data is being used to another table in the db.
This is the relevant flask code:

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = vendorForm()
        vN = history.query.filter_by(id=forms.vendorName.data).first()
        vC = history.query.filter_by(id=forms.vendorCompany.data).first()
        sN = history.query.filter_by(id=forms.sopName.data).first()
        sV = history.query.filter_by(id=forms.sopVer.data).first()

        sopVer = sV.sopVer
        sopName = sN.sopName
        vendorCompany = vC.vendorCompany
        venActivity = request.form.get('venActivity')
        vendorName = vN.vendorName
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        print(venActivity, vendorCompany, vendorName, )
        cursor.execute("select sopVer,sopName,vendorName,vendorCompany from history where sopVer='"+str(sopVer)+"' and sopName='"+sopName+"' and vendorName='"+vendorName+"' and vendorCompany='"+vendorCompany+"'")
        r = cursor.fetchone()
        mysql.connection.commit()
        if r== None:
            print("There are no results to this query!")
        else:
            print(r)
            if venActivity == "Yes":
                print("yes")
                sql = "INSERT INTO activity (vendorCompany, vendorName, assocName, activityDate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
                val = (vendorCompany, vendorName, user, "2008-7-04")
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                mysql.connection.commit()
                cursor.close()
        
        return ('', 204)
```

And my html file:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vendor Details</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/new.css">
  
</head>
<body>
<section class="check_vendor">
    <h1 class="title">Check Vendor Details</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="/result" method="POST" class="vendorForm row">
           {{ form.csrf_token }}
           <div class="form-field col-lg-6">
           <label htmlFor="vendorCompany", class="label">Vendor Company</label>
           {{ form.vendorCompany(class="input-text") }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-field col-lg-6">
           <label htmlFor="vendorName", class="label">Vendor Name</label>
           {{ form.vendorName(placeholder='Vendor Name', class="input-text") }}
           </div>

           <div class="form-field col-lg-6">
           <label htmlFor="sopName", class="label">SOP Number</label>
           {{ form.sopName(placeholder='Enter SOP Number', class="input-text") }}
           </div>

           <div class="form-field col-lg-6">
           <label htmlFor="sopVer", class="label">SOP Version</label>
           {{ form.sopVer(placeholder='Enter SOP Version', class="input-text") }}
           </div>

           <div class="box">
           <input type="checkbox" id="venActivity" name="venActivity" value="Yes">
            <span class="check"></span>
            <label for="venActivity"> Do you want to capture the activity with this vendor?</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-field col-lg-12">
              <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="submit" onclick="validation()">Check Details</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </section>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.12.5/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        function validation()
        {
            swal.fire({
            title:"Vendor Training Valid",
            text:"The Vendor activity has been recorded!",
            icon:"success",
            closeOnConfirm: false
            });
        }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Everything works except I want to show messages from sweet alert depending on various situations.

- So if r==None, users should get an alert that Vendor training not valid.
- If r isn't None, and they haven't checked the checkbox, a different alert and so on.
  The sweet alert is working onClick as expected, but I want to set it dynamically with results from flask. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting a form to a Flask endpoint which returns ('', 204).  Many ways to skin this cat but you could...

- Make a POST http request to the end point using a library like Axios and then depending on the Flask outcome return some JSON onject.  This JSON could hold whether the action is completed successfully or not together with a 'message'.  In your javascript code in the HTML you'd have an if else depending on what was returned and alert accordingly.

or

- You return something like render_template(myhtmlfile.html, sweetalert=true, message="my message")
  and in the myhtmlfile.html have a block which is something like this:

etc etc..........

```
{% if sweetalert=true %}
 <body onload="doMyAlerts('{{message}}');">
{% else %}
 <body>
{% endif %}
```

etc etc...........

...function below...

Together with a JavaScript function, something like:

```
   function doMyAlerts(message)
        {
            swal.fire({
            title: message,
            text: message,
            icon:"error",
            closeOnConfirm: false
            });
        }
```

Not tested but that would be my thinking, I'd go with option one myself.

Comment: So instead of returning 204, I should render a simple html file just for showing message right?